# How to run IntellJ idea from current directory

Tags: linux, intellij

I can run `idea` from current directory. However the terminal will be occupied by idea's background thread. Is it possible to just launch idea without having the terminal occupied? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "occupied by idea's background thread"?  Are you just wanting the command prompt back?  Have you tried `idea &` to background the process?

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes, I want the command prompt back. I tried & to make it run in background. However, the idea is itself a python script, with invocation of os.execv(RUN_PATH, [bin_file] + args). So a & will not take effect.

Comment: `&` on the command line will always background the job and give you control back.  However if the script is generating messages then it makes the screen more messy;  you might want to throw them away and background the job at the same time (`idea > /dev/null 2>&1 &` if you're in a `sh` like shell)

Answer (score 1):

Many GUI based applications do not fork and put themselves into the background, so they keep the command line "busy".  This can be beneficial; it allows you to control-C abort the app in many cases.

If you want to *background* the app then you can do

```
idea &
```

However some apps are also verbose on the output (eg diagnostics or harmless library errors) which can make the screen hard to use.  We can throw away all the output at the same time

```
idea > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You may, instead, want to log these in case an error message appears that you later want to look at.

```
idea > logfile 2>&1 &
```

Finally you might want to "hide" this from the current shell:

```
( idea > /dev/null 2>&1 & ) 2>/dev/null
```

but that's getting complicated :-)  You might find it easier to create a simple script and put it in the `$HOME/bin/` directory.  Call it, for example, `runidea`

```
#!/bin/sh
idea "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Now you can just type `runidea` and it will do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! However, when I do idea ., it is not using current directory. Do you know if there is any idea options I can use? I know other editors like bracket can do so...

Comment: Sorry, that bit I don't know.